# SRWebSocket.m shows warning in Xcode 14, working fine in Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode14

-(NSRunLoop *)runLoop;

{

```
dispatch_group_wait(_waitGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
return _runLoop;
```

}

error:- Thread running at QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE waiting on a lower QoS thread running at QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions

Comment: Seems to be a new warning in XCode 14, since it's inside a third party lib, I guess their repo/ticket manager should be used for that?

Comment: Do you get any solutions?

Comment: You can add `networkThread.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUserInitiated;` to method `+ (NSRunLoop *)SR_networkRunLoop` as indicated at the project: https://github.com/facebookincubator/SocketRocket/issues/661#issuecomment-1703842082